# Springboot application on Heroku

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, heroku

I'm trying to deploy spring boot application on Heroku which is throwing the below error after application deployed.

```
2018-04-13T16:47:42.573257Z system[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-04-13T16:47:42.573323Z system[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2018-04-13T16:47:42.5788Z app[web.1]: 2018-04-13 16:47:42.577  INFO 26 --- [       Thread-3] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@75a1cd57: startup date [Fri Apr 13 16:46:43 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-13T16:47:42.585423Z app[web.1]: 2018-04-13 16:47:42.585  INFO 26 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-04-13T16:47:43.574239Z system[web.1]: Process exited (exit status 143)
2018-04-13T16:47:43.596277+00:00 system[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Below log tells that deployement is successful on port 8085 which is provided manually in the proc file

```
2018-04-13T16:46:47.276958Z app[web.1]: 2018-04-13 16:46:47.276  INFO 26 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8085 (http)
```

procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=8085 -jar target/app.war
```

Any help is appreciated

**Edit:**

@jusermar10 Thanks for the response. Yeah, I'm trying to set staic port and don't want to use the port assigned by heroku as pointed by @user3314492. I know the dynamic port approach works fine. The problem we're facing is that we're trying to use nginx proxy for caching using the builpack at  https://github.com/theoephraim/nginx-buildpack. If we use the dynamic port, nginx config file also uses it which is why it throws the below error

```
2018-04-14T17:09:24.427513Z app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=nginx-start
2018-04-14T17:09:24.440105Z app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:24.440137Z app[web.1]: 2018/04/14 17:09:24 [emerg] 159#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:24.940239Z app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:24.940285Z app[web.1]: 2018/04/14 17:09:24 [emerg] 159#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:25.440529Z app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:25.440569Z app[web.1]: 2018/04/14 17:09:24 [emerg] 159#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:25.940679Z app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:25.940746Z app[web.1]: 2018/04/14 17:09:24 [emerg] 159#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:26.440833Z app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:26.440876Z app[web.1]: 2018/04/14 17:09:24 [emerg] 159#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:10949 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018-04-14T17:09:26.940976Z app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
2018-04-14T17:09:26.941031Z app[web.1]: 2018/04/14 17:09:24 [emerg] 159#0: still could not bind()
2018-04-14T17:09:26.941552Z app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=exit process=nginx
2018-04-14T17:09:26.946943Z system[web.1]: Process exited (exit status 1)
2018-04-14T17:09:26.965949+00:00 system[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the server port as `--server.port=$PORT` in your `Procfile` . Heroku will dynamically assign the port for you.

Comment: I think question is more about how to make this working on static port and not on dynamic port generated by Heroku. I would be interested in knowing how to make this working using static port as well.

Comment: I believe it is not possible to define a static port in heroku. It always assigns the port dynamically. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any heroku dev center article for this.

Comment: @jusermar10 I updated the question. Please see if you can help me.

Comment: @raghav Apologies for late response. I just looked at the nginx build pack config  `nginx.conf.erb` file (`listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;`) . It is listening to the port from environment `PORT` variable. Did you tried changing that?

Comment: @jusermar10 Thanks for the response. I figured it out as per https://dasherydev.wordpress.com/2016/02/27/blogging-on-heroku-with-the-nginx-buildpack-and-contentfocus/. I'll post the answer in a while

Answer (score 0):

You can set the port like this and it will work `-Dserver.port=${PORT:8085}`